show about a guy with a dog and a water plane
somewhere in early 90's, it's a tv show that used to air in my country (possibly American)
This guy had a water plane something similar to this. 
The only scene I could remember the guy has to cross a very soft area (looks to me like a volcanic dry surface, it could break and you can fall inside) on the land, the dog panicked but then he picks up the dog and crosses slowly and he makes it.
Don't know what's the name of the show.  

Could it be Tales of the Gold Monkey?

yes this looks like the one, do you remember this scene if you can help me find that clip on youtube or something?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdFN6agkNnQ

sorry, no I do not remember the scene.
